# Accessing ID of the latest a django model file upload

Tags: django

I have a django model as below:

```
class excel_upload(models.Model):
    my_excel_file = models.FileField()
```

I only every have one file uploaded to it. Because i delete the previous one. However i am accessing the path to the file via the ID. The problem with this is that when I delete the old file and upload the new file the id counter for the file needs to increase in order for me to access the newly uploaded file.
Does anyone know how i can update automatically pull the latest uploaded file?

How i am currently accessing it is by:

```
the_uploaded_excel_file = excel_upload.objects.get(id=11)
```

As you can see this is the 11th time  have had to change the id number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order_by`:

```
the_uploaded_excel_file = excel_upload.objects.all().order_by('-id').first()
```

Descending order of all objects by `id` (Ex: 11,10,9,8...) and getting the first one (`id=11` in this case).
This will give latest `id` object either if multiple objects existed or only one object existed.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: Edited the answer:)

Answer (score 1):

As you said that there will be only one file, use can use the below code:

```
the_uploaded_excel_file = excel_upload.objects.all().first()
```

It will return the only object (first object) or None if there is no object.